# What version of WSDL is supported in dotNet 2.0?

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

What version of WSDL is supported in dotNet 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I figrue it's WSDL 1.1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77axffs8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx
links to
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl

It's really not very clear though from looking at the wsdl XML or Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 are supported](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/soap12inNet20.aspx).

Comment: He/she's not asking about the SOAP version, but rather about the WSDL version. 1.1, 1.2 and even 2.0 (impossible, it's too new) exist.